# user enable/disable rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to allow the interface to change only if the flag enableRotation=1.  I’ve been messing around with all the rotation methods and am getting nowhere.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
enableRotation=0;
currentOrientation=fromInterfaceOrientation;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{



NSLog(@"enable rotation call %i\n",enableRotation);
if(enableRotation)
{  
if ((interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
    (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    ||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)||(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    )
{

    return YES;
}

        }
else if (interfaceOrientation==currentOrientation){


    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

This is what I’m using to display the alternate view....

```
 - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{


if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation))
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayAlternateView" sender:self];
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
  //  enableRotation=0;
    NSLog(@"Rotation disabled\n");

}
else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
         !isShowingLandscapeView)
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
 //   enableRotation=0;
    NSLog(@"Rotation disabled Change to Landscape\n");

}
```

}

Comment: What is it doing? Also why not just do `if(enableRotation) return YES; else return NO;'?

Comment: I tried that.  If I do that it will rotate once correctly.  When I rotate back it will change to the landscape view but display it as portrait (i.e. doesn’t fit properly).  I’d like ti to just stay as the portrait view unless enabled to switch.

Comment: Sounds like your subviews are not set to autorotate properly.

Comment: You should get rid of the `!isShowingLandscapeView` condition. That could cause an issue. Actually get rid of the boolean altogether, You don't need it. You can always get the orientation with `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` or `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`

Comment: Actually you do not need to register for this notification period. You could just use `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` to change the view appropriately.

Comment: That did it...  not sure I fully understand the issue yet, but its working fine now.

Comment: I think I know why. I'll post it as the answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the `!isShowingLandscapeView` condition. That could cause an issue because you may receive that notification multiple times. Actually get rid of the boolean altogether. You don't need it. You can always get the orientation with `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` or `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`

In fact, you do not need to register for this notification period. You could just use `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` to change the view appropriately.

Furthermore, you should make this change as well:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(enableRotation)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```